# my for loop in bash is not counting files and directories

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a small script in bash to practice, I find the syntax of my code correct but I'm surely missing something, this is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

cfiles=$(ls | wc -l)

echo $cfiles

files=0
dirs=0

for look in $(ls); do
   [ -d look ] && $((++dirs)) || $((++files))
done

echo "Files: $files"
echo "Directories: $dirs"
```

I'm receiving a long error message and wrong output:

```
22
test.sh: line 11: 1: command not found
... (until number 48)
test.sh: line 11: 48: command not found
Files: 48
Directories: 0
```

What's wrong with my code? It reaches a count of 48 with command not found, but there are 22 files excluding . and .. then it's doubling the number.

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: ls without options list files horizontally, try `ls -1 | wc -l`

Comment: LMC doesn't make any difference, the result is the same

Comment: `for look in $(ls -1); do`

Comment: I tried LMC but the result is the same

Comment: `[ -d "$look" ]`

Comment: for a first pass at checking syntax consider pasting your entire code (including shebang) @ [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) then make the recommended changes

Comment: @Renato Using `x && y || z` instead of `if x; then y; else z; fi` is not safe, because if `y` fails it will execute `z` as well. In this case, since `$((++dirs))` does fail, this has the effect of counting every directory as a file as well. A more classic example would be `[ -d look ] && ((dirs++)) || ((files++))`, where the *first* directory would also be counted as a file (and if it's not obvious why... that's why `&& ||` isn't safe).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for the great explanation, I'm going to write the same exercise with if condition, I really appreciated your lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$((++dirs))` expands to a number, which is then executed as a command, hence the error `1: command not found`.

To just execute `++dir` without expanding the result, use `((++dir))` without the `$`. Same for `++files`.

> It reaches a count of 48 with command not found, but there are 22 files

Then your file names contain whitespace or special symbols like `*[]?`. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

You can make your script a lot simpler and safer by using globs instead of `ls`. Also, the loop is not necessary with arrays or a function that counts its arguments.

```
#! /bin/bash
count() { echo $#; }
total=$(count *)
dirs=$(count */)
((files=total-dirs))
```

Comment: Socowi it's working in this way:  ``` [ -d "$look" ] && dirs=$((++dirs)) || files=$((++files))``` now I only must solve the problem of multiple lines. If I add an echo, I can see that if the file name has an empty space, the code consider that empty space as a new line, I would need to understand how to make it consider it an entire whole, for example the file name "my code.sh" it is considered as two files

Comment: Just don't parse `ls`. Instead, use `for look in *`. Also, as I said, you can use `((dirs++))` instead of `dirs=$((++dirs))`.

Comment: Socowi the * solved, I have no idea why the * means the files in the current dir and could be used instead of ls, but it solved the problem. I'm not using functions here yet because I didn't get that chapter yet, I wanted to practice with the for loop. Thank you very much!

Comment: `*` is called a *glob* or *wildcard* if you want to google it. Bash replaces it by a list of files. If this answer solved your problem, you can accept it to close your question and say thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Compare how the shell handles expansion:

```
$ ls -t
'this file'   file  'this directory'   directory
$ for f in $(ls) ; do echo "[$f]" ; done
[directory]
[file]
[this]
[directory]
[this]
[file]
$ for f in * ; do echo "[$f]" ; done
[directory]
[file]
[this directory]
[this file]
```

So in one line:

```
$ dirs=0; files=0; for f in * ; do [ -d "$f" ] && ((++dirs)) || ((++files)) ; done ; echo "d: $dirs f: $files"
```

Comment: Thank you, then in general in a for loop the symbol * points at the files in the current folder?

Comment: @Renato In a general shell context, `*` expands to a list of all (non-hidden) items in the current directory. Try `echo *` to see this effect. Similarly. `*.txt` expands to everything with a `.txt` suffix, `/etc/*` expands to everything in the `/etc` directory, etc.

Comment: @GordonDavisson now it's very clear, then instead of writing ```*.*``` (filename and extension) we write only one ```*``` , this helped a lot, very nice of you, thank you :)